# "Will" vs "is going to" for predictions, what is considered an evidence?

Tags: future, will-be-going, will-future

So I know we use *is going to* for predictions with evidence, and *will* for predictions without evidence, but I've read some examples that made me very confused about what evidence actually means.

Take a look at these examples:

> 1. George is very clever. He *[will / is going to]* pass the exam.
> 2. The earth is very crowded. People *[will / are going to)* live on the moon.
> 3. The country's energy supply *[will / is going to]* increase after discovering a new natural gas field.

Comment: You haven't established the two things you said you "know". I don't think the language splits the two like that.

Comment: Well in the textbook I'm studying it does.

Comment: In that case, many people *are going to* disagree with your textbook and many people *will* disagree with your textbook. If there is a particular structured context in which the two are different, you'll need to describe that context.

Comment: My textbook just says that "will" is used for predictions that are based on feelings or guessing, for example: I think Brazil will win the match. "is going to" on the other hand, is used for predictions with evidence which you can see in the present, for example: I see clouds. It is going to rain. That seems very clear so far. But then I see this example: Mark is very clever, he will pass the exam. In this example, the textbook says that we can't use is going to because being very clever is not evidence. So I'd love to hear your opinion on that particular example.

Comment: I think your textbook is being too dogmatic. In many cases it is not: either _will_ is right or _going to_ is right. Swan in _Practical English Usage_ (p193) says: "The differences between the structures to talk about the future are not always very clear-cut. _Will/shall_ and present forms (especially _going to_) are often both possible in the same situation... ".

Comment: @MathewHany I understand your frustration. The thing is that there are many different uses of both *going to* and *will*, and the difference won't really be clear until you are familiar with all of them - but the textbook has to introduce things one at a time or it will be chaos. In all 3 of your sentences, both options are possible with minor alterations. You can certainly set up an example where *George is very clever, he's going to pass the exam for sure* works. It doesn't work very well in the original sentence but the reason is not really to do with *will* vs *going to* for predictions.

Comment: It's just ridiculous to say that in that sentence, the fact that he is clever is not the evidence on which you are basing your prediction. One thing that runs through the different uses of *going to* is that they tend to be about our subjective intentions and expectations. IN THIS USE *will* is more objective, so if you make a prediction with *will*, you are presenting it as if it were a fact - a kind of physical inevitability and not just a prediction that you have made after weighing up the evidence. I think that is what the book is trying to get at.

Comment: Notice that when we don't want the implication that it is an objective fact, we need another verb to change the meaning, as in *I think Brazil will win the match*. If you say *Brazil will win*, the impression is much more *fact: not up for discussion, don't ask me what makes me think so*.

Comment: ... but if you say *I think Brazil will win the match* it could be a total guess, whereas *I think Brazil are going to win* conveys that you know something about it and have made an assessment. *Brazil are going to win* is the same except that here you are insisting that your assessment is right.

Comment: @Minty. You make a lot of good points. In my opinion choosing the best future construction is, along with article use, the most difficult aspect of English grammar for language learners.

Comment: @Minty Thank you! Very detailed and informative explanation. So if I understood correctly, you can use both depending on what you mean. And in the examples above, you cannot choose one over the other unless you know what the speaker was trying to convey. Is that correct?

Comment: "_You can use both depending on what you mean_." Exactly!. Swan gives examples: _"What will you do next year?_" (open question about the future) - "_What are you doing next year?_" (emphasis on fixed arrangements) - _"What are you going to do next year?_" (emphasis on intentions).